# Docker - run a sql file in container

Tags: docker

Any attempt at this has failed.
I have a large sql script in my laptop, and I want to run it in my docker container.

I believe I have to copy it first=:

```
docker cp ./my_cool_script.sql container_mssql_1:/my_cool_script.sql
```

This seems to run and doesn't give any success or failure so I assume its ok?

I then try:

```
docker exec container_mssql_1 -u sa psql databasename sa -f /my_cool_script.sql
```

but I just get:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"-u\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

Any ideas, or is there a better way to do this.  The file is quite large (30MB).

Comment: It would help if you could share the contents of your `Dockerfile` to get a better idea of the context, specifically from which base image you're building.... Rather than "manually" doing the `cp` step, you could add that to your `Dockerfile` (or a derivative `Dockerfile`).

Comment: this would be a 1 off that I would do locally to set up my local env, using mssql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the sqlcmd utility that comes with the SQL Server image. You will indeed need to copy the script into the container first.

`docker cp script.sql <container_id|container_name>:/tmp/`

Then, use the sqlcmd utility inside the container. 
`docker exec -it <container_id|container_name> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P <your_password> -i /tmp/script.sql`

sqlcmd docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files 
Docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

Tested on image :2019-CU8-ubuntu-16.04 with a ~700mb script

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

> docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

The `-u` option needs to come *before* the name of the container.

```
docker exec -u sa container_mssql_1 psql databasename sa -f /my_cool_script.sql
```

That's why it was complaining "there's no executable on my PATH named `-u`". It thought you wanted to run a command called `-u`.

Comment: I get this: unable to find user sa: no matching entries in passwd file

Comment: looks like your original error is now solved, and now you have a new error. is your question "solve every error until my whole use-case works"? that's too broad for this forum. StackOverflow is for minimal, reproducible problems. it would be appropriate to open a new question for this next error, but only after demonstrating sufficient research (I say this because the new error — like the first one — is a really clear, simple error; please demonstrate that you actually tried to solve this problem independently).

Comment: ask yourself: _why am I writing `-u sa`?_ do you expect a user named `sa` to exist? the error is telling you that there's no such user.

Comment: are you perhaps referring to a _PostgreSQL user_? `docker exec -u` refers to _users within the container's Operating System_, **not** PostgreSQL users.

Comment: Thanks - its MSSQL not postgres.  I was trying to execute the sql using the sa account

Comment: okay, I was misled because in your command you use a PostgreSQL client.

Answer (score 0):

When using `docker exec` you're ultimatively executing a command inside the container. The syntax for `docker exec` is

```
docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]
```

With the command you've used it sees "-u" as COMMAND, which is not an executable it can find in the $PATH.

I'm not an expert in mssql or psql, so I don't know what you're trying to achieve with `-u sa` before the psql command.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your output, you can see that the executable that docker is trying to run is `-u`, which corresponds to your attempt to set the user - essentially you've just got your `docker` command parameters in the wrong order!

Try putting the user option straight after the `exec` and before the container name...

```
docker exec -u sa container_mssql_1 psql databasename sa -f /my_cool_script.sql
```

You also might not actually need to explicitly specify the user with the `-u` option.